# Where does KDE 5 store user-specific keyboard layout choices?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, configuration, kde, keyboard-layout, kde5

I made a short script which can export various KDE settings from user home directory to use as a basis for a quick setup of the desktop environment on a different machine.

I was successful with all the settings that were of interest to me, but only one is elusive: I can't seem to find where the chosen keyboard layouts are stored. Basically, I would like to get to all the configuration that can be manipulated from the KDE settings application under the *System Settings* > *Hardware* > *Input Devices* > *Keyboard* > *Layout* tab (particularly the layouts themselves and the keyboard shortcut to switch between them). Does anyone have any idea? Maybe these settings are not specific to KDE and manipulate different configuration files? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some time of searching and playing with `grep`, I was able to locate the configuration file: `~/.config/kxkbrc`.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: I see the `LayoutList=us` in that file, but do you know the location where these layout are saved?

Answer (score 0):

I am running kde4 on CentOS 7 and I found these settings on `~/.kde/share/config/kxkbrc`

I realize this is more than one year old and that OP is asking for KDE5, but if you come here and would like to start somewhere, please search where I mentioned.

Now I want to know how to force refresh those settings.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you have a related problem, please don't post this as part of an answer to the original question. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to comment on other people's posts to request clarification or add details. In the meantime, you can ask your own question if it is sufficiently distinct. You can link to this question if you think that helps establish context.